# How to add 'new field' color based on 'existing field' percentage in array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have JSON data, it has `percent` field. In each record I want to add new field `color` based exiting field percent. if percent

```
>95% then add green
90-95% then add yellow
<90% then add red
```

This is my data

```
{
    "name": "ABER",
    "percent":100
},
{
    "name": "ABER",
    "percent":92
},
{
    "name": "HDCC",
    "percent":93
},
{
    "name": "HDCC",
    "percent":90
},
```

I am looking for this output

```
{
    "name": "ABER",
    "percent":100
    "color":"green"
},
{
    "name": "ABER",
    "percent":92
     "color":= "yellow"
},
{
    "name": "HDCC",
    "percent":93
     "color":= "yellow"
},
{
    "name": "HDCC",
    "percent":90
    "color":= "red";
},
```

Is that possible to do that, how can I do it?

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/7hr2oxpc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use js map function and add another index to object inside array.
See below code.

```js
var a = [{
    "name": "ABER",
    "percent": 100
  },
  {
    "name": "ABER",
    "percent": 92
  },
  {
    "name": "HDCC",
    "percent": 93
  },
  {
    "name": "HDCC",
    "percent": 90
  }
];
a = a.map((v) => {
  if (v.percent > 95) {
    v.color = "green";
  } else if (v.percent >= 90 && v.percent <= 95) {
    v.color = "yellow";
  } else {
    v.color = "red";
  }
  return v;
});
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could mutate the current list/items and just add the new property:

```js
var a = [
  { "name": "ABER", "percent": 100 },
  { "name": "ABER", "percent": 92 },
  { "name": "HDCC", "percent": 93 },
  { "name": "HDCC", "percent": 90 }
];

for(let item of a){
  item.color = item.percent > 95 ? "green" : 
    item.percent > 90 ? "yellow" : 
    "red";
}

console.log(a);
```

or you create a new list with new items that contain the new model:
*(See the topic of immutability)*

```js
var a = [
  { "name": "ABER", "percent": 100 },
  { "name": "ABER", "percent": 92 },
  { "name": "HDCC", "percent": 93 },
  { "name": "HDCC", "percent": 90 }
];

const b = a.map(({name, percent}) => {
  const color = percent > 95 ? "green" : 
    percent > 90 ? "yellow" : 
    "red";
    
  return {name, percent, color};
});

console.log(b);
```